# "Filtering" a value through range limits and retrieving a value form a 2D array using said value?

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, multidimensional-array, while-loop

Sorry for the confusing title. To be clear, I'm trying to:

1. Get user input (ex: x = 10)
2. "filter" the input through range limits (ex: {0, 5, 11, 16, 20})
3. Assign the while-loop control variable to **x** based on how "deep" into the array it gets (ex: loops thrice since 'x' is greater than 5 but not 11, so x = 3)
4. Use that value to retrieve a 2D Array value (ex: pricing[0][x] = 1)

The issues arise as well... it doesn't work as intended. The program only outputs "1" no matter what I enter for the quantity. Below is the code I used. I can provide anything missing

```
//Main.java
    public static void orderMenu(Orders ord) {
        Scanner uIn = new Scanner(System.in);
        int sAmt = 0;
        int mAmt = 0;
        int lAmt = 0;
        int x = 0;
        //Placeholder Function until I can think of something better
        while(x != 4){
            x = uIn.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Enter amount desired: ");
            if(x == 4){
                break;
            }
            //This function will stack on the amounts the user enters
            switch(x){
                case 1:
                    sAmt += uIn.nextInt();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    mAmt += uIn.nextInt();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    lAmt += uIn.nextInt();
                    break;
            }
            //Prints the list out again
            System.out.print(pList); //I removed this from the snip since it is gargantuan
        }
        //Calls Orders.java and calculates prices
        ord.setSmall(sAmt);
        ord.setMed(mAmt);
        ord.setLarge(lAmt);
        System.out.println(ord.reciept()); //Displays calculated price. Only smallPrice for now
    }

//Calc.java code
    public String receipt(){
        calculations();
        String receipt = "\nDebug Price:" + smallPrice;
        return receipt;
    }

    public void calculations(){
        int[] rangeLim = {0, 5, 11, 16, 20}; //limits array
        int[][] pricing = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5},     //Row 1
                           {3, 6, 9, 12, 15},   //Row 2
                           {5, 10, 15, 20, 25}};//Row 3
        int sub = rangeLim.length - 1;
        
//This is where I am having trouble:

        //finds the y for pricing[x][y]
        while(sub >= 0){
            //System.out.print(sub);
            if(smallOrder >= rangeLim[sub]){
                smallOrder = rangeLim[sub];
            }
            if(mediumOrder >= rangeLim[sub]){
                mediumOrder= rangeLim[sub];
            }
            if(largeOrder >= rangeLim[sub]){
                largeOrder = rangeLim[sub];
            }
            --sub;
        }
        
        //Assigns price value to variable
        smallPrice = pricing[0][smallOrder];
        mediumPrice = pricing[1][mediumOrder];
        largePrice = pricing[2][largeOrder];
    }
```

I'm not sure how little or much I should have included but I hope this is enough.

Just to make my goal clear: If input 1, it will wait to receive input for "sAmt". After typing a value such as "16", it will loop again. Inputting 4 will end the loop, and I should see "4" or pricing[0][3]

I'm a little lost here.